# Double quotes show up as HTML entities in topic summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

In the topic list of a tag in Documentation, double quotes in the excerpt show up as `&quot;`.  They look normal in the topic itself though.

For example, in the [list of topics for Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/erlang/topics):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little overzealous encoding never hurt anyone, right? Right?

A fix is in the pipeline and will go live with the next production build. Thanks for the report!